# How to filter objectlistview's TreeListView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, objectlistview

I tried to filter `TreeListView` using delegates like in the documentation: [Filtering ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/filtering.html?highlight=filtering)

So it goes like this:

```
this.myTree.ModelFilter = new ModelFilter(delegate(object x) {
    return (((MyTreeNode)x).Type == type); // this code doesn't work, why ?
});
```

As result, `myTree` should include all nodes with `.Type` property is equal to `type`, in my case there are no nodes in the tree, why ???.

But, if I set `.Type` property to type of the root node, then it will be only one root node in the tree, so in this case it works.

**ETA:** Why filtering with the above code doesn't work ?

Answer (score 2):

From your question, it's not entirely clear what your `TreeListView` structure looks like. But it may have something to do with the fact that you want to filter child items that haven't been fetched yet (unexpanded nodes)?

From the tutorial link you already referenced:

> **Filtering and TreeListViews**
>   Filtering and TreeListViews interact in a predictable but perhaps unexpected fashion.
>   Filtering considers only rows that are currently exposed (that is, all their ancestorss are expanded).
>   Within those rows, rows will be included by the filtering process if they or any of their descendents will be included by the filtering. (Yes, this is recursive). If a bottom level child matches the filtering criteria, then all its ancestors will be considered to have matched as well and thus will be shown in the control.
>   In the majority of situations, this gives the most predictable and useful visual results.