# ObjectListView filtering on non visible model object properties

Tags: c#, filter, filtering, objectlistview

I am new to using the ObjectListView component in c# and have spent many hours trying to find a solution to this issue, so please excuse the simplicity of this question . I am looking to be able to filter an ObjectListView (actually a tree view) by object properties on the model object that are not added as columns and are therefore not visible. In particular i am trying to filter objects based on an internal key that is not user friendly.

I have tried using the TextMatchFilter but it only works if the property is added as an aspect of a column and is visible which looks ugly and unprofessional for an internal key.

Can anyone direct me down the right lines please?

Comment: are you using this: http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html

Comment: You say that you get what you want if you add the key as an aspect of a column. Couldn't you just make that column invisible? Or will that prevent the filtering from working?

Comment: Or maybe you could just filter on the object level and refresh the OLV contents?

Comment: I will also point you to a recent answer by @Rev1.0: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472066/how-to-filter-objectlistviews-treelistview